# how can i print a using class Employee here and having trouble inheriting

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class Person:

    def _init_(self):
        self.A=1

class Employee(Person):

    def _init_(self):
        print(A)

object1=Person()
object2=Employee()
```

Comment: `_init_` is not the same as `__init__`. Your "constructors" are never called. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: @tobias_k well there's a few more things wrong here than that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yep, already noticed and retracted my close vote.

Comment: i don't how it missed that __init__ i have there in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually multiple problems with that code, besides the misspelled constructor...

1. Your `_init_` method should be `__init__`, otherwise it's not a constructor but just a method that happens to be called `_init_`, and thus never called.
2. You have to call the constructor of the super-class, or `A` will not be set, e.g. using `super().__init__()` or `Person.__init__(self)`
3. You have to use `self.A` to read the field `A` of the instance; otherwise it will look for a local variable called `A`

This should work:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self):     # misspelled
        self.A = 1

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self):     # misspelled
        super().__init__()  # call super constructor
        print(self.A)       # use self.A
```